# Can I install Google Edition Android on an HTC One X+?

Tags: custom-roms, vanilla-android, htc-one-x+

Recently, the HTC One Google Edition has been released which has Google Android 4.2.2. I'm currently using an HTC One X+ and I want to install Google's Android on my mobile. 
I've found some links on how to install vanilla Android on the HTC One:

1. [Redmond Pie](http://www.redmondpie.com/install-google-edition-stock-android-on-htc-one-how-to-tutorial/)
2. [XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=43015772)

I'm willing to install that on my mobile. Can I do that, and if so, are there any cons to doing that?

Is it possible to install vanilla Android on my phone so that every time the Android is updated, I get the updates directly from Google?

Comment: For the second part of your question: That's only possible for Nexus devices. For all other devices, drivers etc. need to be updated/integrated as well before an Android update becomes availabe to them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A ROM for the HTC One won't work on the HTC One X+. Despite the name similarity, they're completely different phones, with different hardware inside. (The HTC One X+ has a Tegra 3 SoC, while the HTC One has a Snapdragon.)

If you want to install a "stock Android" ROM on this phone, you'll have to find one first, and as there isn't a Google Play Edition for the One X+, this is very unlikely to exist. You might be best with a custom ROM that doesn't have many customizations. Generally, custom ROMs don't update over the air: you need to reflash whenever you want to upgrade to the latest version.