# Install Cyanogenmod on HTC One X+

Tags: cyanogenmod, 4.2-jelly-bean, custom-roms, htc-one-x+

I want to install Cyanogenmod on my HTC One x+. In the [Official Website](http://www.cyanogenmod.org/) there is no official release for HTC One X+. Can I install from the [HTC One X Version](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Endeavoru_Info) or the [HTC One XL Version](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Evita_Info) ?? and there is an [Unofficial release for HTC One X+ Cyanogenmod](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2067325&) or should I install this version ?? Is there any particular reason or defect why Cyanogen didn't release one officially for HTC One X+ ??

Can you please give me the way to Install Cyanogenmod on my Phone ?? I'm a *Newbie*

Comment: Similar question here: [Can I install Google Edition Android on an HTC One X+?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/49220/16575) ("Google Edition" refers to the HTC One X without the +). Besides, same author: Krishna, this is a general rule. So you don't need to re-ask it for each other ROM you might find. It's different hardware, so the answer is always "No".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTC One X version won't work on the HTC One X+, so if you want to install Cyanogenmod, it'll have to be the unofficial build you link to.